# Suppress delete sheet warning in excel using c++

Tags: c++, excel, com, msdn

I am trying to delete Excel sheet via C++ code but randomly it fails. Here is the code:

```
HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pXlSheet, L"Delete", 0);
```

This function returns ***S_OK*** even delete sheet failed but the sheet isn't deleted from the workbook.
I suspect this fails because warning prompt appears.How to avoid warning prompt?
your suggestion is highly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all the methods and came to conclusion.This one works fine and put display alerts off.

Code snippet:

```
VARIANT vBool;
vBool.vt=VT_BOOL;
vBool.boolVal=FALSE;

hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT, NULL, _pXlApp, L"DisplayAlerts",1,vBool);
```

This method returns S_OK:)